# Finding maximum and minimum in inteval using dynamic memory allocation C program

Tags: c, arrays, statements

Hello i am trying to find the maximum and minimum in a given interval using dynamic arrays. It works to find the maximum and minimum, but not in the given number interval. Where am i going wrong ? Please help.

```
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #endif

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <Windows.h>

    int main(){
        int i, n;
        int *bliznak;
        int max = 0, min = 0;
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int p = 0;
        printf("Give upper and lower limit");
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

        printf("enter elements");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        bliznak = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
if (bliznak==NULL)
{printf("ERROR"); exit(0);}
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            printf("enter number %d    ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", bliznak + i);

        }




        for (i > a; i < b; i++){
        max = *(bliznak + i);
        min = *(bliznak + i);

            for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {

                {

                    if (*(bliznak + i)> max)
                    max = *(bliznak + i);


                    if (*(bliznak + i) < min)
                        min = *(bliznak);
                }
            }

    }   
        printf("\n MAX Numb %d\n", max);
        printf("\n Min Numb %d\n", min);

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You can start by checking the return value of calloc() for success. Also, do not cast the return value of calloc().

Comment: Please use a tool that indents your code properly. This would have helped you to spot your error right away.

Comment: You assign a value to `bliznak[0]` but it is never checked.

Comment: When you ask *"in a given interval"* do you mean an interval of array indices, or an interval of array values? Because the code suggests the former, even if it worked.

Comment: well i have a bunch of numbers in that array i want it to display the maximum and minimum value between 1 and 100 for example...

Comment: Use `perror` -not your `printf`...- or `strerror(errno)`  on failure of standard functions like `fopen` or `calloc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fixed version of your code

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(){
    int i, n;
    int *bliznak;
    int max = 0, min = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int p = 0;
    printf("Give lower and upper limit");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);                 

    printf("enter elements");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    bliznak = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("enter number %d    ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", bliznak + i);
    }


  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)         // changed loop condition
  {
      if( ( *(bliznak + i) ) >= a && ( *(bliznak + i) ) <= b )
      {     
         max = *(bliznak);
         min = *(bliznak);
         break;
      }
  }

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
                if( ( *(bliznak + i) ) >= a && ( *(bliznak + i) ) <= b )  // this checks the interval
                {

                  if (*(bliznak + i)> max)
                    max = *(bliznak + i);


                  if (*(bliznak + i) < min)
                    min = *(bliznak + i);          // you forgot + i
                }

        }


    printf("\n MAX Numb %d\n", max);
    printf("\n Min Numb %d\n", min);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Now lets loop at the problems

```
for (i > a; i < b; i++){
```

That loop is wrong. You are checking the indices, not the values. You should change it to

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)         // changed loop condition
 {
    if( ( *(bliznak + i) ) >= a && ( *(bliznak + i) ) <= b )
    {   
      max = *(bliznak);
      min = *(bliznak);
      break;
    }
}
```

Then, in

```
if (*(bliznak + i) < min)
     min = *(bliznak);
```

You forgot the `+ i`. It should be

```
min = *( bliznak + i );
```

To check for the intervals, use this

```
if( ( *(bliznak + i) ) >= a && ( *(bliznak + i) ) <= b )
```

as indicated in the code above.

Comment: "min = *(bliznak);" I wrote it with the intention of not having the same values for min and max. I should do more research on pointers.

Comment: ...it's unnecessary to have a loop to initialise `min` and `max` to the last array elements. They *could* be set to `a` and `b`, but there is an inherent problem in that there might not be *any* values in the interval.

Comment: @WeatherVane , you are right. I missed that part. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

remove the semicolon after the for loop here: and add block instead.

```
for (i > a; i < b; i++);---->

 for(i>a;i<b;i++){}
```

since you are checking between the interval a and b

Comment: Actually this `for` statement is completely bogus, the change on the `;` doesn't even help.

Comment: Agreed, `for(i>a; ...` starts the loop with `0` or `1` but doesn't assign a value to `i`.

Comment: I did change it aswell, but it didnt help.

Comment: well well where is your initialisation for i in the for loop....hmm this loop statement is completely wrong..